# Difference between means

Tags: mean, stata

I want to compare two means.
The first one is the mean over several questions, in which people had to decide how they would split a hundred euro between two different persons.
The second mean is the same one, but with one additional question added in the mean!
Now I want to test for significant differences in these two means. Ideally I should not find any significant difference when I add the result of those one question to the mean, but that I have to test.

Can sombody help me which statistical test I need to use and ideally how I can implememt it on Stata?

Comment: What exactly is the *question* you are trying to answer by doing this? Comparing something vs something + something else does not make much sense, you more likely want just to test is the mean of the additional question is non-zero.

Comment: People have to decide how to split money between a group member (who has some same characteristics as you, f.ex same religion) and a stranger: The average alloction to the stranger gives me a measure for in-group favoritism! Now I add a new question with another in-group. So for example when on average a person gives 50 to in-group and 50 to stranger, does this average stays the same when I add the new question! Ok sorty I think I cant explain it very well

Comment: Still, you should probably edit your question to add a more detailed description. It doesn't sound like what you are trying to do is what you actually should do.